# Within panel estimator - how to perform standard error adjustment?

Tags: panel-data, fixed-effects-model, plm

I am fitting a within panel model via glm in R and I am trying to understand standard error adjustment as in plm package (to account for loss of degrees of freedom via demeaning):

Consider the following within model fitted via glm:

```
library(plm)
data("Produc", package = "plm")

df_train_within <- Produc %>%
  group_by(state) %>%
  mutate(gsp = gsp - mean(gsp),pcap = pcap - mean(pcap))

fit.glm <- glm(gsp ~ pcap, data=df_train_within)
```

Output glm model:

```
summary(fit.glm)$coefficients[2,1:2]

 Estimate   Std. Error 
 2.8493965  0.1189785
```

Now consider the output from the model fitted via plm:

```
fit.plm <- plm(gsp ~ pcap,
data = Produc, model = "within", index = c("state","year"))

summary(fit.plm)$coefficients[1,1:2]

Estimate   Std. Error 
2.8493965  0.1225697
```

As can be seen, the coefficient estimates are the same for glm and plm, but the standard error is too low for glm. According to Cameron/Trivedi we need to inflate the residual variance by factor `1/[N(T-1)-K]*[N*T-K]`. Performing this adjustment for the glm standard error using `N=48, T=17, K=1` I was not able to re-produce the standard error reported in the plm package.

Can anyone help me in explaining how the adjustment is performed in the plm-package? I wasn't able to find the relevant piece of source code which could also be very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The degrees of freedom adjustment for fixed effects models in `plm` is handled by the internal function `plm.fit`. Here is the relevant part:

```
if (model == "within") {
    pdim <- pdim(data)
    card.fixef <- switch(effect, 
                        individual = pdim$nT$n,
                        time = pdim$nT$T,
                        twoways = pdim$nT$n + pdim$nT$T - 1)
    df <- df.residual(result) - card.fixef
    vcov <- result$vcov * df.residual(result)/df
}
```

Please take heed: As the way you estimate the model with `glm` includes an intercept and `plm` does not include an intercept, your manual adjustment would need to take care of that as well if you want the numbers to match excactly.